# Use scale_y_time to convert MS to Minutes and Seconds in Boxplot (GGPLOT)

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a dateframe like below, where the column time is in milliseconds

```
id | group | time
1    |   A   | 1400003
2    |   B   | 1604203
3    |   A   | 170203
```

I am creating a boxplot ussing GGplot

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=group, y=time, fill=group)) + 
  geom_boxplot()
```

[image]

How can I use `scale_y_datetime()` or `scale_y_time()` convert the tick marks of the Y axis to the following format `M:S`?

Answer (score 5):

We can convert the time values to a difftime object (in seconds) and then format the y axis labels:

```r
df <- read.table(text = 'id | group | time
1    |   A   | 1400003
2    |   B   | 1604203
3    |   A   | 170203', sep = '|', header = TRUE)

df$time <- as.difftime(df$time/1000, units = 'secs')

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df, aes(x=group, y=time, fill=group)) + 
  geom_boxplot() +
  scale_y_time(labels = function(l) strftime(l, '%M:%S'))
```

[image]

Created on 2018-05-04 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

Answer (score 2):

How about this?

```
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)

#choose correct 'origin' as per your data
ggplot(df, aes(x=group, y=as.POSIXct(time, origin="1970-01-01", tz="GMT"), fill=group)) + 
  geom_boxplot() +
  scale_y_datetime(breaks = date_breaks("24 hours"),
                   labels = date_format("%b %d, %Y\n%H:%M:%S")) +
  ylab("Time")
```

**Sample data:**

```
df <- structure(list(id = c(1, 2, 3), group = c("A", "B", 
"A"), time = c(1400003L, 1604203L, 170203L)), .Names = c("id", 
"group", "time"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L
))
```